# No package httpd available using yum on CentOs 7

Tags: apache, centos, yum

When I try:

> *yum install httpd*

I get the error:

```
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com
 * extras: mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com
 * updates: mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj82s.png)

Comment: there is no repo for httpd in your system. First update OS db then give a try OR download httpd rpm and install.

Comment: I updated the yum, but it does not work.

Comment: Download RPM from here and try to install.. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ ... still, you found any dependencies issue then you need to create the local yum repo to install httpd

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

`httpd` package can be installed from default CentOS repositories, 'base' and 'updates' (for a newer version).

```
# repoquery -i httpd | grep -i repo
Repository  : updates
```

Make sure that you have repository file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` or create it manually, with, at very least, the following content:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Then do:

```
# yum clean all && yum update -y && yum install httpd -y
```

Comment: Thank u. I solved the problem by change the mirrorlist. My server is aliyun. I installed CentOs 7.3 on the server by default setting. It's mirrorlist is  http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/. I add other baseurl from china. But it's not work. After that, I replaced the system with CentOs 7.4. Reinstall httpd and make it.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this issue as well and found the following in yum.conf:

```
exclude=httpd nginx php mysql mairadb python-psutil python2-psutil
```

Removing httpd from there let us install it